# RESTful Struts2 webservice with multiple parameters

Tags: java, rest, struts2

I am writing a webservice that has multiple parameters in the url. I know I can do this with jax-rs, but can I do this with Struts2?

What I might have done in JAX-RS:

```
    @Path("/{service}/{companyName}/{acctId}")
    public Response acceptPostAccount(@PathParam("service") String service,
                                @PathParam("companyName") String companyName,
                                @PathParam("acctid") String acct)
```

What I would like in Struts2:

```
@Path({@PathParam("service"),@PathParam("companyName"),@PathParam("acctId")})
private String service;
private String companyName;
private String acctId;

// Setters omitted for brevity.
```

Or any other sort configuration that can map path parameters to fields on the action.

All the documentation and examples I have seen on line show a single parameter called Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Set these constants in struts.xml.

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
```

Then define action as:

```
<action name="/{service}/{companyName}/{acctId}">
   ...
</action>
```

Of course you need to have setters for properties in your action.

It is called [Advanced Wildcards](https://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-AdvancedWildcards) in Struts2 and it is available since 2.1.9.